# How do callbacks work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I've come across an example in my code that lead me to revisiting callbacks in Javascript, which I was always shaky on.

The example: I need function "type" to execute and finish before function "erase". I could add some timer to type that ensures it ended, but I'd like to find a better way.

Digging into type:

```
function type() {
    captionEl.html(caption.substr(0, captionLength++));
    if(captionLength < caption.length+1) {
        setTimeout('type()', 50);
    } else {
        captionLength = 0;
        caption = '';
    }
}
```

The function isn't ended until caption = " " (nothing") - thats when I'd like to see erase() run.

So, do I pass callback as a parameter in type (like type(callback)) and then execute callback where caption is set to nothing? But how do I 'test' the type function to have caption as ""?

Comment: If your code is executed on old computers in the corrected format, then every 50 milliseconds, the type function is called which means recursive function calling. This is a good way to lock up an old computer. Thats unless you do better checking of the input string.

Comment: @Mike: It's not recursive, it's scheduled. Also, every 50ms wouldn't slow down Pentium3 running at at 200MHz or more (even on IE5). On a 133MHz machine you may notice a slow-down. I know this because I used to write such web apps way back in 2001-2002 (back then they called them dhtml, not web apps) and my workstation was a 200MHz Pentium3 while my laptop was a 133MHz Pentium2.

Comment: What do you mean by 'test'? What exactly do you want to test here? And yes, passing a callback as a parameter is one way of doing that. Another way would be to use a promise.

Comment: @SamuelLiew: "...which causes it to fire immediately"* That's not true. It is executed in global scope, but it is not executed immediately.

Comment: Don't pass `setTimeout` a string, just pass it a reference to `type`: `setTimeout(type, 50)`. Using a string implicitly `eval`s it, needlessly slowing things down, it is equivalent to `setTimeout(eval('type()'), 50)`.

Answer (score 0):

If `erase` is always called after `type` is done, you don't need a callback, just a normal function call:

```
function type() {
  captionEl.html(caption.substr(0, captionLength++));
  if(captionLength < caption.length+1) {
    setTimeout(type, 50);
  } else {
    captionLength = 0;
    caption = '';
    erase();
  }
}

type();
```

If whatever happens when `type` is done could vary, that is when you would need a callback:

```
function type(callback) {
  captionEl.html(caption.substr(0, captionLength++));
  if(captionLength < caption.length+1) {
    setTimeout(type, 50);
  } else {
    captionLength = 0;
    caption = '';
    callback();
  }
}

type(erase);

// somewhere later in the code it does something else after type is done
type(duplicate);
```

A [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) is just a function that is being passed in a variable. JavaScript has [first-class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function), meaning they can be passed around as arguments or returned by other functions. [This article](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) does a pretty good job of explaining callbacks more thoroughly.